# How to do MERGE method like cypher in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

```
g.addV('person').property('name','Tim')
```

I got V[0] node

```
g.addV('person').property('name','Tim')
```

I got V[1] node with with the exact same label and key value again.

I just want V[0],if there is V[0] exist, V[1] can not be added.

Comment: I think you can `dedup()` it after adding them to remove the duplicates. I hope [this helps](https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/wAAH5qX7MI4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this with Gremlin today is to use the `coalesce` pattern as follows:

```
g.V().has('person','name','Tim').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(),addV('person').property('name','Tim'))
```

This will return the existing vertex or if it does not exist will create it and return the new vertex.

You can read more about this in the [Gremlin Recipes](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) and in [Practical Gremlin](http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#coaladdv) .

Comment: I just registered,I click the useful button many times but it didn't work,I think it's my reputation level not enough.I'll check later.Sorry for that...